# Проверить наличие файлов в каталоге

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть созданный каталог папка myIcons. Как сделать проверку, есть ли в папке какие-нибудь файлы или папка пуста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот у меня есть такая проверка:

```
File directory = new File("/path/to/folder"); // тут вашу папку указываете
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
// это вообще не папка
if (contents == null) {

}
// Папка пустая
else if (contents.length == 0) {

}
// В папке что-то есть
else {

}
```

можно добавить или убрать условия при необходимости (например проверять на наличие определенного файла в папке или что-то типа такого).